# Populate decoded data into dropdown

Tags: php, json

I am having 2 files, one to fetch ajax and to decode it. the other (page2.php) is modal popup in which I want to populate the received data from page1.php.

page1.php is below which returns invoice numbers perfectly.

```
$newArr = array();
$decoded = array();
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($decoded ['invoices'] as $result) {
    $newArr = $result['invoiceno'];
    echo $newArr; //JUST FOR DEBUGGING
}
```

page2.php is a modal where I try to get the received data and populate into a dropdown.

```
function sort_(){
    global $newArr;
    $output='';
    $output.= '<option value = '.$newArr.'>'.$newArr.'</option>';
    return $output;
}
```

I know I am not looping the array to sort. I have tried different ways like below which didn't work.

```
function sort_(){
    global $newArr;
    global $result;
    global $decoded;

    $decoded= json_decode($result, true);
    $output='';
    $output.= '<option value = "Select INO">Select Select INO</option>';
    foreach($decoded['invoices'] as $result) {
        $output.= '<option value = "'.$newArr.'">"'.$newArr.'"</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

The error that I am getting in developer console is;

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\order\page2.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\order\page2.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
```

where I am stuck?

Comment: _"page1.php is below which returns invoice numbers perfectly."_ - That code will only ever return one single invoice number, since the `return` will stop the foreach from continuing. It's basically the same as just having: `return $decoded['invoices'][0]['invoiceno'];` without the foreach. If you want to add them to an array, you need to do: `$newArr[] = $result['invoiceno'];` and then have `return $newArr;` after the loop.

Comment: How do you run page1.php and page2.php?

Comment: you need to check if  $decoded is empty or not before doing foreach

Comment: @M.Eriksson right, I think the main problem here is data is not going from page1.php to page2.php

Comment: You should really test each piece of code separately and check that they actually produce the result you're expecting and also debug the variables to see that they contain what you think. It seems like it's a bit all over the place right now, and it's hard for us to give you a proper answer since we don't know how it's all connected. Are you calling page1.php and page2.php separately in JS, or is one including the other in PHP (since you seem to be using the same variables)?

Comment: I am returning the array from page1.php and set it to newArr and including in page2.php and using the same global variable in order to populate it to the dropdown @M.Eriksson

Comment: _"If i debug page1.php and print the result I am able to get all the invoices using this foreach(...) { return ... }'"_ - That's not possible. The return _will_ stop the foreach from continuing. https://3v4l.org/pofWe - Even without the `return`, the `$newArr` variable will just contain the number from the last iteration, since it will be overwritten on each iteration. However, the code you just posted in the comment differs slightly from the code in the question. Please make sure the code in the question is an _exact_ copy of your real code. Also add more context to the code.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Hi Erikson, I appreciate your response. Thanks. what I am actually doing in page 01 is.. check the edited question. first code block. afterwards, I am fetching the array to page2 and populate in dropdown. I am stuck at populating. Printing, getting the result I want in page1.php is totally fine.

Comment: @M.Eriksson you can join if you can. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241684/array-populate

Comment: If you do `$newArr = $result['invoiceno'];`, then `$newArr` will only contain the invoiceno from the last iteration, not all of them. It's still very unclear how the different code snippets are connected. I've already asked for clarification, plus you've basically asked us to help you debug code you're not even using (since your rewrite is different from the original code in the question), so good luck, but I'm out...

Comment: $decoded variable containts multiple invoices. as per the first block that has been shared, it will print each and every invoice numbers since I am looping through multiple invoices. 
foreach($decoded ['invoices'] as $result) {
    $newArr = $result['invoiceno'];
    echo $newArr; 
} all my concern is to get the $newArr array to page2.php and populate it to a dropdown. why it is so complicated @M.Eriksson

Comment: Again, `$newArr` **_will not be an array_**. You 're **_overwriting_** that variable on each iteration. As I've already suggested, you need to do: `$newArr[] = ..` (see the `[]`?) so you push the new numbers to the array instead of of **_overwriting_** the variable.https://3v4l.org/H6mmd. And also, since we _have no idea_ how page1 and page2 are connected (different requests? is one including the other in PHP?), _it's impossible_ for us to know how to use data from one file in another. You're making it complicated/impossible to answer since you don't answer our questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was an easy fix.

page1.php had

```
global $decoded;
$decoded= array();
$decoded= json_decode($result, true);
```

page2.php

```
function sort_(){
        global $decoded;
        global $result;
        $_invoiceReturn='';
        $_invoiceReturn .= '<option value = "Select Invoice">Select Invoice</option>';
        foreach($decoded['invoices'] as $result) {
            $invoice_number = $result['invoice_number'];
            $_invoiceReturn .= '<option value = "'.$invoice_number.'">'.$invoice_number.'</option>';
        }
        return $_invoiceReturn;
    }
```

I am looping the invoices on page2.php based retrieving page1.php JSON. I decoded the json so it becomes a normal PHP array and looping through.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the records from the DB (In case your data is not in form of a json string in the DB you don't need to decode)
2. Create the following functions :

```
function getOptions($acc, $record){
    return $acc."<option value='".$record['your key']."'>".$record['your key']."</option>" ;
}

function createOptionsHtml($records) {
    return array_reduce($records, 'getOptions') ;
}
```

Hope I got your problem right.